# React ERROR in Entry module not found - Visual studio RC 2017

Tags: .net, node.js, reactjs

Hello i have an issue when running my webpack (task runner)

[Run - development img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5worB.png)

Note that i have installed npm also

here is my webpack

```
"use strict";

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js'),
    entry: {

        client: './client.js'
    },




    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/build'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Transform JSX in .jsx files
            //{ test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                }

            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        // Allow require('./blah') to require blah.jsx

        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','json']
    },
    //externals: {
    //    // Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
    //    // bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
    //    react: 'React'
    //},
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        })
    ],
}
```

And here is my package.json

```
    <{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "~15.4.2",
    "react-router": "~4.0.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.7.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "install": "^0.8.7",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.15.0",
    "webpack": "1.12.9"
  }
}
```

and here is the client.js

```
var Components = require('expose?Components!./components');
```

also i have two components that i try to put together but with no luck

this is the class StorePicker:

```
import React from 'react';

 class StorePicker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Any where else
        return <p>Hello</p>
    }
}


 export default StorePicker;
```

and this is the index class, that imports StorePicker

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './css/style.css';

import StorePicker from './components/StorePicker';

ReactDOM.render(<StorePicker />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Please explain your issue in the text of the question, and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of slashes on windows try to change

```
entry: {

    client: './client.js'
},
```

to

```
entry: {

    client: path.join(__dirname, './client.js'),
},
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is still an error ![Error in entry module](http://imgur.com/Jz9BZqJ)

Comment: Try to remove this line context: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js'),